# How do I round 12.443 to 12.40

Tags: android

I'm making a calculation and I'm getting 12,443. I want to round it to 12,40. This is the way I'm trying to do it but I'm getting 12 instead of 12,40

```java
float result = Math.round( (new Float(result1)*0.3) + (new Float(result2)*0.7) );
vprosvasis.setText( Float.toString(result) );
```

Examples:

- if I get 12,70001 I want to round to 12,7
- if i get 13,4402 to round it to 13,4
- 11,19 to 11,2

So, the final number will always be in ##.@ format

Comment: You need to make your question clearer, and clean up the code a bit. Is your question simply, "How do I round 12.443 to 12.40"?

Comment: I dont really understand your problem. Are you rounding up decimal points too early, so your final calculation is thrown off?

Comment: Do you want to round to the nearest .1 then? If you're going to 2DP, then 12.44 would be the correct rounding, 12.4 at 1DP. Or do you want to go to 1DP and add an extra 0?

Comment: float result=Math.round( (new Float(result1)*0.3)+(new Float(result2)*0.7));

                vprosvasis.setText(Float.toString(result));}

Comment: if i use math round then it makes 12,72 to 13..but i want to make it 12,7..or,if it was 12,75 to make it 12,8.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: may i have a more clear answer please?

Comment: Since you haven't stated your question clearly it is very difficult for anyone to give you a clear answer.  How many DP do you want the answer?  What is your criteria for rounding?

Comment: i have edited my question.the answer i would always like to be ##.#

Answer (score 16):

```
(float)Math.round(value * 10) / 10
```

should give you the result you want.

Comment: Thanks. btw, it's Math.round() in my case (Android 4.2.2 API17).

Comment: Yeah I guess it doesn't need to be more complicated than this. And if it's desired to make 12,443 to 12,40 it should be possible to just add "0" to the string where this value is to be printed

Answer (score 2):

i have this function to do it :

```
public static float get_ROUND(float p_VALUE, int p_DECIMAL)
{
    if (p_DECIMAL == 0) return (float) Math.round(p_VALUE);

    long l_LNG = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= p_DECIMAL; i++)
    {
        l_LNG = l_LNG * 10;
    }

    return (float) Math.round(p_VALUE * l_LNG) / l_LNG;
}
```

Comment: - First i testing if 0 decimal and return the round value (Math.round)

Comment: - the for multiply 10 for each decimal wanted

Comment: - Math.round return no decimal : we get the round of the value * a multiple of 10 and divide the result by the same multiple of 10

Answer (score 1):

```
DecimalFormat  twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
yourvalue=  Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(yourvalue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DecimalFormat`, but specify the correct rounding mode. By default it uses `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`, but `ROUND_HALF_UP` is common for a lot of financial applications.

If you really want to find and use the rounded value in further calculations (which is unusual because it produces inaccurate results), you can use `BigDecimal`.

I assume `result1` and `result2` are `String` instances.

```
float value = Float.parseFloat(result1)*0.3F + Float.parseFloat(result2)*0.7F;
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(value));
BigDecimal rounded = d.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

The main advantage to using `BigDecimal` as opposed to multiplying, rounding, and dividing, is that you can select the rounding mode (half-up, half-even, etc.). A `BigDecimal` is a lot more expensive to manipulate than a primitive `float`, so this would be a better option for an interactive financial application than a scientific simulation.

You can then use the `rounded` value as is, or [convert it to a `float`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#floatValue%28%29). You can convert to a `String` with the [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString%28%29) method, but this is better done with a locale-sensitive `DecimalFormat` object, which will accept `BigDecimal` with its [`format()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    vprosvasis.setText(""+new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.#").format((result1*0.3)+(result2*0.7)))
```